# Read column of string from csv file with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

I have the following data in a csv file:

```
00:1A:1E:35:81:01,  -36,    -37,    -36
00:1A:1E:35:9D:61,  -69,    -69,    -69
00:1A:1E:35:7E:C1,  -95,    -95,    -71
00:1A:1E:35:9D:65,  -66,    -67,    -67
00:1A:1E:35:9D:60,  -67,    -68,    -68
00:1A:1E:35:9D:63,  -66,    -68,    -68
```

I am unable to read first column with MATLAB, which contain strings.

Comment: tell us what have you tried so far .

Comment: I tried csvread(filename, row, column, range). It's not working

Comment: try the second/third outputs from `xlsread`. `csvread` only works on numerical data.

Comment: @Anmol: the documentation says covered is for numeric data only. Try textscan or (if excel is installed) xlsread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
xlsread(file.csv);
```

instead of csvread. It returns [num, txt, raw], where num contains all cells parsed to double (NaN where it was not possible), txt all cells as text ('' where conversion  to num succeeded) and raw with all cells as strings.